# VS Team Services gives false error on continuous integration 'This version control host is unsupported'

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

hoping someone has seen this before.

When I try to enable continuous integration in Visual Studio, using Visual Studio Team Services, I get the following error:
"**This version control host is unsupported. Repositories must be hosted on VSTS or GigHub**." This error gets zero results in google.

As you can see in the screenshot, the solution IS hosted by VSTS.

[image: Screen shot of my configuration dialogue]

Explaining the screen shot:

1. Section 1 in the pic is the pop-up that appears after clicking 'Configure Continuous Integration' in the VS2017 status bar.
2. Section 2 is my VS team explorer window.
3. The grey boxes are the company website '*mycompany*'.

Additional facts:

1. The VSTS account is owned by admin@*mycompany*.com, but my dev account, jason@quantumland.com, has full contributor permissions to the project. I get the same error whether red box 1 above has my personal account selected or admin@*mycompany*.com
2. The current loaded solution is the basic starter '.NET Core Web application' in VS2017 Community edition. No authentication selected, no changes to the auto-generated code.
3. I can build and run the solution locally, check in the solution to VSTS, see the code in the VSTS repository, publish to Azure web app, etc. Everything seems to be working but this.

Appreciate any help. My best guess is that my security permissions are wrong in VSTS, but both accounts are members of the 'admin team' group, and admin@*mycompany*.com is the creator/owner of the VSTS account and repository, so I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use TFVC for version control and get CI/CD to work. Following the newer instructions provided by @starain-MSFT:
[Continuous Integration](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core)

This sets up CI/CD using the VSTS web portal exclusively. It works, but if I click 'configure continuous delivery' in the VS2017 status bar and use that form, I continue to get the error above.

If anyone posts an answer that fixes the exact question asked I'll update and mark that as the answer. Good news is that you can indeed use TFVC with CI/CD. yay, and thanks to @starain-MSFT for the updated link.

Answer (score 1):

You are using TFVC version control, the continuous delivery is used for Git version control, so you need to add a new git repository ([can be in TFVC team project: Use Git and TFVC repos in the same team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/team-projects)), and use this git repository as source control.

Article about TFVC and Git: [Choosing the right version control for your project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc)

Comment: I'm not certain that's correct, Continuous Integration (automatically build) and continuous Delivery (automatically publish) can us TFVC per this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso

Comment: Got cut off.  Anyway, maybe that has that changed?  But on reading this I noticed the note under section 2: "Visual Studio Team Services only support CI deployments of Visual Studio Web Applications at this time. Web Site projects are out of scope."  I'm not certain which project type I used, I was trying to select a very basic one to troubleshoot the issue. It also says to select .NET Framework 4 or 4.5, think I targeted 4.6?  I'll try with a different 4.5 Web Application.

Comment: @Jason It is Continuous Delivery extension limit. The visual studio team service support CI deployments for web application and web site. The link you provided is XAML build, which is old, you can use new build system. Refer to [Implement continuous deployment of your app to an Azure App Services website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps) to deploy your web app to azure.

Comment: You can use TFVC for version control.  I had selected a web application, that wasn't the problem. The problem was twofold, both of which were in the steps included in the link you provided. I'll post it as an answer, but thanks for the link because that lead me down the right path. I still can't use the 'configure for continuous delivery' in the VS2017 status bar, it all has to occur in the VSTS site.